# auto adjusting the text layer's time to the length and position of an audio layer

Tags: after-effects

I just wonder if there’s any way/script/expression to make one layer mirror/copy/adjust itself to another layer’s lenght? Now i’m working on some quotes and the audio is much longer than a text layer. There are a 200 quotes. Is it posssible to make the text layer to follow the time of the audio layer? and position itself automatically?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2mXb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to kBar as snipped.
first, you select all the layers that need to be extended, the last one you choose is the layer whose length you need to extend.
the script simply sets the outPoint of the selected layers at the time of the outPoint of the last selected layer.

```js
app.beginUndoGroup ("reMap layer");
testRemap();   
app.endUndoGroup();
function testRemap() {
    var curComp = app.project.activeItem;
    var layers = curComp.selectedLayers;
    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length-1; i++){
        layers[i].outPoint = layers[layers.length-1].outPoint
    }
}
```